# Implementing a Card- and CalDAV Client

Tags: caldav, carddav

I was asked to develop a web-application that can talk to my company's Card-/CalDAV-Server (Kerio Connect). I've spent the past hours trying to find a suitable library but there doesn't seem to be one that is functional and still maintained. Milton looks great, but it's written in JAVA, which neither I nor my co-workers have worked with.

Instead, I'll probably have to write something myself, preferably in PHP or JavaScript. My question is; how? I really like how the entire thing is http-based, but aside from the RFC, there's very little documentation to be found. While I did manage to get a few of my curl-requests answered, others failed without me understanding why:

```
curl -X PROPFIND -u username@domain.tld:password -H "Content-Type: text/xml" -H "Depth: 1" --data "<propfind xmlns='DAV:'><prop><displayname /></prop></propfind>" http://webmail.domain.tld/carddav/users/domain.tld/.public
```

This works. I get a response containing "Public Folders (domain.tld)", which is, well, what I asked for.

```
curl -X PROPFIND -u username@domain.tld:password -H "Content-Type: text/xml" -H "Depth: 1" --data "<propfind xmlns='DAV:'><prop><addressbook-home-set xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:carddav"/></prop></propfind>" http://webmail.domain.tld/carddav/users/domain.tld/.public
```

This one, on the other hand, returns 403 - Forbidden.

Both requests are probably wrong in some way - they're simply what I managed to piece together.

So how can I approach this? Would it be best to just read the RFC's, top to bottom? So far, they haven't been that helpful.

**Edit**:

I've read both articles on sabre.io. They did help me to some extend. However, I'm still not able to get the actual contact-data. I've managed to get a summary that contains UUID's for our shared address book, but how to use those UUID's, I have no idea.

Further, neither article goes into much detail as to how things are supposed to work. For example, first the CardDAV-related article states that *the ctag must be stored for subsequent requests*, then, only a few lines later, it mentions that the server *might* not support it at all. Further down, I learn that the ctag is supposedly a tag that lets me know if something has changed on the server; *This is the purpose of the ctag. Every time anything in the address book changes, the ctag must also change.* So..., what happens when my server doesn't support it? How do I know if it does? Requesting it simply yields a 403 - forbidden.

This is the request I'm using;

```
curl -X PROPFIND -u username@domain.tld:password -H "Content-Type: text/xml" --data "<d:propfind xmlns:d="DAV:" xmlns:cs="http://calendarserver.org/ns/"><d:prop><cs:getctag /></d:prop></d:propfind>" https://domain.tld/carddav/users/domain.tld/.public/
```

To get the aforementioned summary of our public address book, I used;

```
curl -X REPORT -u username@domain.tld:password -H "Content-Type: text/xml" --data "<c:addressbook-query xmlns:d='DAV:' xmlns:c='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:carddav'><d:prop><c:address-data></c:address-data></d:prop></c:addressbook-query>" https://domain.tld/public-contacts/domain.tld/
```

Comment: Your --data string is invalid (wrong quotes)

Comment: To get the actual card-data: Did you try a `GET` using one of the responses to the `PROPFIND` on the addressbook uri?

Answer (score 1):

The SabreDAV website has a pretty good article on how to write CalDAV and CardDAV clients: [Building a CalDAV client](http://sabre.io/dav/building-a-caldav-client/).

Besides, SabreDAV likely has a lot of the code which you would need to implement a DAV client in PHP. Other library implementations are listed on the [CalConnect CalDAV website](http://caldav.calconnect.org/implementations/librariestools.html).